# Why do odoo 11 wizards being not responding?

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-11

In Odoo v11 the wizards are not working only when I restore the database.

The addons have only a single path. But in the log, it is showing somewhat other paths along with the given path like this.

```
2019-08-29 13:12:08,835 8853 INFO ? odoo: addons paths: ['/home/username/.local/share/Odoo/addons/11.0', '/home/username/odoo/odoo11/custom/samurai', '/home/username/odoo/odoo11/odoo/odoo/addons', '/home/username/odoo/odoo11/odoo/addons']
```

The path which I have given to the Odoo config file only is

```
'/home/username/odoo/odoo11/custom/samurai'
```

In the above path, only all the modules including custom and base are available. Right now I'm using the Ubuntu 19.04 OS with Pycharm.

I have tried with Odoo-bin in the terminal by giving the addons-path, but the result is exactly the same as above.

Comment: have you upgraded all installed modules after restoring db? If yes, please specify how you are running Odoo.

Comment: Nope. Just restored the db only.

Comment: what do you mean not responding? and Odoo required some modules for example web module must be loaded at least to be able to create a database, this why you see other paths by default. can you explain more about your problem errors?!! screen photos any thing could help

Comment: Do you start your odoo server with a run script? Often the addons path is modified there.

Comment: Odoo addons path is not modified. I have clearly mentioned above.